# Why does my design elements look different in all browsers? UPDATE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, responsive-design

Forgot that this is a question and answer site and not a help forum. I got banned for this message :(

> I have four content boxes, but they do not look similar in chrome and
>   safari. I have used these boxes. If someone could take a look
>   HERE and see what i have done wrong.

Comment: I bet you didn't use a CSS reset

Comment: Don't post links to a "live" version of your problem. Once you fix the problem, the links mean nothing. Post the actual code, reduced to the specific problem.

Comment: I agree, I looked at the boxes in chrome and safari and they look the exact same.

Comment: Thnaks. I had to include a CSS reset - sweet!

Comment: @user2162729 Bootstrap comes with Normalize, which is a reset. You don't need to add another one in. See: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#global

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this on line 544 of main.css:

```
542    .ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon {
543      color: #Fff;
544*     animation: 300ms ease 0s normal none 1 moveFromBottom;
545    }
```

You're using the non-vendor-prefixed variant of `animation`. Firefox recognizes this attribute, but WebKit (chrome, safari, etc) don't ([more info on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)). Add the vendor prefixed variants of the animation attribute or remove it completely to make it consistent.